# construction order of static member in class

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int x;
public:
    A() { cout << "A's constructor called " << endl;  }
};

class B
{
    static A a;
public:
    B() { cout << "B's constructor called " << endl; }
    static A getA() { return a; }
};

A B::a;

int main()
{
        cout<<"Hi\n";
    B b1;
    B b2;
    return 0;
}
```

In this program, I am expecting output to be

```
Hi
A's constructor called
B's constructor called
B's constructor called
```

But the output is

```
A's constructor called
Hi
B's constructor called
B's constructor called
```

Comment: Why did you expect that? What made you believe that construction of `B::a` should be delayed?

Comment: I overlooked d fact dat a is declared global!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior your seeing is proper because both `main()` and `B::a` reside in the same translation unit. From the standard, leaving out the thread-local initialization stuff,  you're seeing *dynamic initialization* of an object with *static storage duration*. The standard does have rules of how/when objects with static storage duration are initialized:

> **C++ § 3.6.2 [basic.start.init]**
>
> 2. Variables with static storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place.

There's more dealing with `constexpr` declarations, but that doesn't apply to your code. So we at least know the memory backdrop of object `B::a` has been zero-initialized, goodie, but when does the constructor actually fire in this case? That is called *dynamic initialization*, and according to the standard:

> **C++ § 3.6.2 [basic.start.init]**
>
> 4. It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the first statement of `main`. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the first statement of main, it shall occur before the first odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

In your case, as circumstances would have it `main()` is in the same translation unit as `B::a`, In staying with the standard, while `main()` may start execution *before* static-storage objects are initialized, `main()` itself resides in a translation unit, and as such all static-storage objects requiring dynamic initialization in the same unit as `main()` **must do so** before `main()` begins execution. Therefore `B::a` is constructed before the first statement of `main()`.

Why should you care? Well, `B::a` could always reside in s *different* translation unit than `main()` (ex: `b.cpp`), and your results *may be different*, but still in compliance with the standard. At that point it is implementation-defined whether `B::a` would be dynamically initialized before `main()` begins execution, but again, *must* be initialized before any function or variable in the `b.cpp` translation unit is odr-used.

Comment: I don't think it is about implementation. The text you quested clearly states that static objects have to be initialized before the first use of any function from the same translation unit. Since in this case everything is in a single translation unit, it immediatley guarantees that static objects will be initialized before `main`. If the OP relocates the static object definition to a different translation unit, then it will indeed become implementation-defined.

Comment: I don't see what it has to do with `<<` at all. All I see is that `main` and `B::a` are defined in the same translation unit. That is already enough to say that `B::a` should be initialized before `main` begins execution.

Comment: @AndreyT Perhaps I don't understand the standard text then (and it seems likely). It clearly allows `main()` to begin execution before objects with static storage duration have been dynamically initialized under the specific condition that no function or variable in the same translation until as the one being initialized has been accosted. Are you saying precisely because `main()` is in said-same translation unit it therefore qualifies and thus `B::a` has guaranteed setup before `main()` is entered? I would certainly agree with that, as it seems this is more to handle statics in *other* units.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. The function does not have to be related to the static object in any way. By the moment a function from some translation unit is used all static objects from the same translation unut have to be initialized. This means that all static objects that happen to share the translation unit with `main` will be initialized before `main`. Static objects in other units might be initialized later.

Comment: @AndreyT yeah, the latter was what I thought *may* happen here, but `main()` being in the same unit certain makes sense for a predictable initialization of all statics in said-same. Thanks for the clarification. I'm going to try and rescue this answer so it is at-least worth of the check it momentarily has.